# ClassCastException String to MValue, java 8

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-7, classcastexception

I have an interface

```
public interface MValue extends SomeOtherInterface, Serializable
```

and I use it in another interface like so

```
    public interface DomainObject extends Iterable<FieldValueAssociation>, Cloneable, Serializable {
     void add(DomainField field, MValue... values);
<T> T get(DomainField field);
    }
```

and when I call this in some other class I set

```
subDomain.add(DomainField.ZIP, d.get(DomainField.ZIP));
```

On java 7 this works fine, but on java 8 I get **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to net.blabla.domain.MValue**

`d.get(DomainField.ZIP)` should return String, and it is, but it cannot be casted to MValue, and I dont know why? Can someone explain or refer me to some documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show a full, compilable (in Java 7) example?

Comment: @assylias code is exactly the same in Java 7, it compiles in java 8 too, i get this in runtime, this is a huge Spring app,  the classes are to big to paste them here, that's why I summarized it on this.

Comment: If `d.get(DomainField.ZIP` returns a String I don't see how your code would compile, whether with Java 7 or 8. That's why I suggest you tried to create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us understand what is happening. You don't need to paste all those classes, only a minimal example that shows the problem.

Comment: Sorry it returns Generics this is get method <T> T get(DomainField field);

Comment: Something like this: https://gist.github.com/assylias/a4e7b5fd46d53bce59c5

Comment: @assylias I updated the code in question, but yes, something like your github example

Comment: You should fix the method `<T> T get(DomainField field)` whose signature is broken by design. It claims to be capable of returning whatever type the caller wishes, which obviously won’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So does that work?

```
subDomain.add(DomainField.ZIP, d.<String>get(DomainField.ZIP));
```

Here I explicitly give the type for `T` as being `String`, type checking will happen nevertheless, but it makes clear to the compiler what is expected.
This call should work for Java 7 and 8.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I fixed it with d.get(DomainField.ZIP).toString(), it gives the same result like your answer. Also thanks to @assylias for making an interest in my problem. Thanks guys.